# Rails Flash notice not on url but in object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my user controller/model I'm creating a user.
When I redirect to user

```
format.html { redirect_to(@user, :notice => 'You have successfully registered!') }
```

I get a nice notice displayed on my page

When I try to redirect to a different controller without an object

```
 format.html { redirect_to(:controller => 'profiles', :action => 'index', :notice => 'You have successfully registered!') }
```

I get the notice on the url and not displayed on my page.

```
profile?notice=You+have+successfully+registered%21
```

is there any way to put the notice into some object and display it on my page?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
format.html { 
 flash[:notice] = 'You have successfully registered!'
 redirect_to(:controller => 'profiles', :action => 'index') 
}
```

or try this

```
format.html { redirect_to(:controller => 'profiles', :action => 'index'), :notice => 'You have successfully registered!' }
```

Comment: first option just worked fine.
Thank you for this quickness :)

Comment: The second option is a syntax error in my application (ruby 1.8.7, Rails 3.2.9).
``
`format.html { redirect_to(:action => "show_matches", :id => @trial.id), :notice => "Candidate was successfully registered."}`
The error marker points at `)`.

Answer (score 4):

This is answered in more detail and also asked with more examples in the following post:

[Why does Rails flash[:notice] ="msg" work where :notice => "msg" doesn't?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637656/why-does-rails-flashnotice-msg-work-where-notice-msg-doesnt)

In short the usage below is putting the **notice** in a hash with **controller and action**, but what you want to do is have the **notice** in a second hash as per the [redirect_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html#method-i-redirect_to) signature.

```
redirect_to(:controller => 'profiles', :action => 'index', :notice => 'You have successfully registered!')
```

Here is how it can be done properly in one line:

```
redirect_to({:controller => 'profiles', :action => 'index'}, :notice => 'You have successfully registered!')
```